# try-catch in function and in main script?

Tags: php, exception

I am looking to get some advice on best practice for throwing exceptions and catching them. I am using a 3rd party library for connecting to Amazon mws API. This library already throws exceptions which I am catching within a function.

My question is, should this function pass the exception onto the main script by using a try-catch? e.g.

```
function myFunction() {
    try {
        $obj = new Object();
        $obj->makeCall();
        return $obj->getData();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        throw new Exception('There was a problem with the library '.$ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

then in the main script;

```
try {
    //make the call
    $response = myFunction();
} catch (Exception $e){
    //log error
    $logger->error("log error");
}
```

Comment: If you must catch the exception (which you shouldn't if you are only re-throwing it) then the [exception constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.construct.php) takes a 3rd parameter which is the exception which caused it.

Comment: you don't need to or you may pass $ex variable to the new exception you are throwing just like @apokryfos said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are catching the exception in the main script, you don't need to catch it in your function `myFunction` until you need to do some processing in your function.

The control will return to the exception being catched in the main script if any of it's children or children's children and so on throw an exception.